# Geometric realization of crossed square

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, internal-categories, crossed-modules

Given a crossed square of groups, you can "totalize" it and get a 2 crossed module in the sense of Conduché "[Modules croisés généralisés de longueur 2](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(84)90034-3)", then you can apply his machinery to get a simplicial group and apply the classifying space functor to get a simplicial set. On the other hand, given a crossed square, by reconstructing the 2fold category internal to groups and taking the multinerve, you get a bisimplicial group. From a bisimplicial group, there are certainly tons of way to get a simplicial set by first associating to it a trisimplicial set. So my questions are the following :
$i)$ Is there a way to go from trisimplicial sets to simplicial sets such that both constructions are isomorphic ? I see two possible ways: the first one using two times the codiagonal functor $\nabla :ssSet \rightarrow sSet$ of Artin-Mazur as the composite $sssSet: \overset{s\nabla}{\rightarrow}ssSet \overset{\nabla}{\rightarrow} sSet$. The second one is a kind of a "cotrigonal" functor in the spirit of the codiagonal, i.e. as the right adjoint of the precomposition with ordinal sum $\oplus : \Delta^3 \rightarrow \Delta, ([k],[l],[m]) \mapsto [k+l+m+1]$.
$ii)$ Is there any reference where the simplicial set associated to a crossed square have been performed ?
The point is that I do have crossed square and I don't want to totalize them and then apply Conduché's machinery, mainly because I don't really understand it.

Comment: Carrasco, P., Cegarra, A.M., Garzón, A.R., 2010. The classifying space of a categorical crossed module. Mathematische Nachrichten 283, 544–567. https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.200610827

There, it’s also explained how a crossed square gives rise to a categorical crossed module, so you can compose both constructions.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if something similar has been done in higher dimensions ? I would also be interested in crossed n-cube, for general n. That is why I was looking for a construction using multinerve and codiagonalization functor which seems natural if we want to do something with crossed n-cube (for example S.Paoli has made something in this direction in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2009.05.013)